# node js how to a save a response in a http server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am creating my server like so

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){....}
```

and I need to be able to save the response for a later time to send it out because I leave the function to do another callback function. ex:

```
function sendRes(){
    response.writeHeaders(200); //global response
    response.end();
}
```

anymore questions please ask

Comment: Put that function inside the callback (closures)

Comment: Interpreting your question: Once you receive a request event, you need another callback function before forming a response. So you need to put sending the response in a callback function in/after a callback function; Of which the latter is necessary to send your response in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  // Do something here
  function sendRes() {
    response.writeHeaders(200); //global response
    response.end();
  }
  sendRes();
});
```